# https version of site not loading on some computers in network

Tags: networking, dns, cache, windows-server-2012, https

I have just installed an SSL certificate for a website. This site was previously http only.

On the company's internal network, most people are now able to access this site through both https and http, but for me and one or two others, it times out when trying to load via https. This is in IE, Firefox and Chrome on Windows 7 64 bit.

If I try to access it via https on my Android phone when connected to the internal wifi, it also doesn't load however if I try on the same phone connected to mobile data it works fine.

This seems to me that there is maybe some kind of caching going on somewhere but I don't know where to look for this.

I think it is affecting people who have recently loaded the site via http and then try to load through https.

I have tried ipconfig /flushdns to no avail.

Both http and https versions of the site are on the same ip address and point to the same folder.

Network is a Windows network with Windows Server 2012 at its core and about 300 users.

No other https sites are affected.

Comment: Do you mean `ipconfig /flushdns` ???

Comment: apologies yes. have edited.

Comment: Have you added the certificate to the certificate store?  I am going under the assumption that the certificate is self-signed.

Comment: No it is not a self-signed certificate. If it were, then the browsers would surely prompt with a message as such. In fact there is a timeout occuring as if the browser cannot communicate with the server (or is at least not getting the expected response).